# Matching String Instead of str_detect

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have two dataframes say x & y. Both of have same column D. I want to extract value from E column of
y and feed it into F column of x. the dataframes with million of records. 
currently i am using

```
for ( i in 1:dim(x)[1])
{

      ind<-which(str_detect(y$D,x$D[i]))
      if (length(ind)>0)
      {
        x$F[i]<-y$E[ind]
      }  

}
```

This is quite slow. Can anyone help to make it faster.

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fuzzy` join

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(x, y %>% 
                     select(D, E), by = 'D')
```